# easelJS & adobe_animate blur filter not working

Tags: javascript, blur, createjs, easeljs, tweenjs

I'm trying to implement a blur filter in animateCC2019.
I succeeded in creating the blur... But have trouble animating it.
Here is what I put in animate CC, in the action panel at that time for that movieClip instance:

```js
var myBlur = new createjs.BlurFilter(25, 25, 1),
nb = this.mario_mc_1.nominalBounds;
this.mario_mc_1.filters = [myBlur];
this.mario_mc_1.cache(nb.x, nb.y, nb.width, nb.height);
this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(myBlur).to({blurX:0, blurY:0},25).wait(1));
```

here is a codepen :

https://codepen.io/trufo/pen/wvrvaOX

codepen doesn't show the blur, but on this site it does :

https://banner-testing.neocities.org/

and here is the link to the fla file:

https://www114.zippyshare.com/v/V5m0z67k/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to solve this so I ended up using pixi.js with it's animate extension.
It works ok but when the blur is extreme it tends to give weird pixelated results.
https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters-basic/blur.js
The best way I found to make a blur is with SVG and GSAP. Unfortunately I haven't found an easy way to make animate and GSAP's ticker play nice and consistently with all browsers (mainly Safari)